# Flight cancelled: try an ADR or directly to claims management company?

Tags: air-travel, legal, airlines, ryanair, disputes

My Ryanair flight was cancelled (officially delayed 18 hours) because a crew member was sick and according to the EU regulation 261 and sources like [this](https://www.bottonline.co.uk/blog/judge-rules-crew-sickness-does-not-excuse-airlines-from-paying-flight-delay-compensation) and [this](https://euroflyrefund.com/en/extraordinary-circumstances) I should be entitled to a 400€ (> 1500Km within EU) plus taxis from/to the airport. I got an email from Ryanair denying the compensation:

> Following a review of your claim, we regret to advise that no liablity
> to compensation arises under the EU261 regulation as your flight was
> disrupted due to unexpected crew sickness out of base.
>
> If you are unhappy with our decision, you can take your complaint to
> your local Alternative Dispute Resolution (ADR) body, details of which
> can be found in our help centre page on our website.

Should I try with an ADR, like mentioned in Ryanair's email, or go directly to a claims management company like AirHelp or Flightrights? With the latter, I'm almost sure that I'll win, but they charge ~30-35% of the money, which is a lot. Are ADRs of any help or just a waste of time? Will going to an ADR prevent me from latter going to court? There is only one ADR listed in the European Commission's [list of ADRs](https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/odr/main/?event=main.adr.show2) for transport services in Ireland: NetNeutrals EU Ltd,

Answer (score 1):

According to the [EU](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm#ex-circumstances-delayed-1)

> If the airline does not provide you with a satisfactory explanation, you can contact your national authority documentfor further assistance.

With a linked [PDF](https://transport.ec.europa.eu/document/download/d7b5dd33-4083-4faa-8132-b6dc8b3a1c07) containing the list of the respective autorities

I highly suggest you to follow EU guidance and contact your home country's authority, especially since you have the cancellation/delay reason in wrting (if you don't live in the EU, I think you would be able to contact the Irish authority as Ryanair is based there)

Comment: What makes you think the national authorities will actually do something? Most government agencies of this type are just window dressing, but there is rarely any tangible action. It's like putting your number on the "do-not-call" list. The spammers don't care can call you anyway